# Sprig load more: prevent repeating entries with random output

Tags: entries, plugin-sprig, random

On an article page i show 3 random entries, and a load more button via sprig.

```
{% set query = craft.entries().section(section).orderby('RAND()').offset(offset).limit(3) %}

{% set items = query.all() %}
```

Pressing the load more button shows 3 more Entries.

Now i get duplicate entries. How can i prevent this and exclude the already shown
entries?

As described [here in video 2](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/videos#1-introduction-to-sprigcart) in the sprig documentation, if i have only one random article and want to
reload the component and show another random article, i can exclude the last shown entry in the query.

set a last entry id:

```
{% set lastEntryId = lastEntryId ?? 0 %}
```

in the link/button to get the next random entry, set the value:

```
s-val:last-entry-id="{{ entry.id }}"
```

and in the query i exclude the last used id:

```
{% set query = craft.entries().section(section).id('not ' ~ lastEntryId).orderby('RAND()').offset(offset).limit(3) %}
```

How can i adopt this to my setup?
I guess, get the already 3 first shown entries and put them in array and exclude these ids in the query (how do i do that?) and update this array after showing more entries with the load more button.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question, you just need a list of IDs to exclude rather than a single ID.

Here's an example in which the incoming IDs are [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/split.html) and [merged](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/merge.html) into the [id](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#id) query parameter to filter out the entry IDs.

The [join](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html) filter is then used to output the merged last IDs with the IDs from the query.

```
{% set lastEntryIds = lastEntryIds ?? '' %}
{% set lastEntryIds = lastEntryIds|split(',') %}

{% set query = craft.entries()
    .section(section)
    .id(['not']|merge(lastEntryIds)
    .orderby('RAND()')
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(3) 
%}

{% set items = query.all() %}
{% set ids = query.ids() %}

{{ hiddenInput('lastEntryIds', lastEntryIds|merge(ids)|join(',')) }}
```